# Complex grid with images

Tags: html, css, gallery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have the below grid and I want to transform it into code.

[image: grid]
I searched about grids like this and the only reference was about the [masonry library](https://masonry.desandro.com/) but didn't help me.

Another approach was with [css only](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/67gz2) but I couldn't understand the logic behind this.

Any help for a good start to continue with will be appreciated!

Comment: [Try checking this out](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a CSS grid with the adequate number of rows and columns, and the distribute the elements as the design:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: column dense; 
    width: 95vw;
    height: 95vh;
}

.vertical {
    grid-row: span 2;
    background-color: tomato;
}

.horizontal {
    grid-column: span 2;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.square {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#v2 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
#v3 {
    grid-column-start: 6;
}
#v4 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
#v5 {
    grid-column-start: 5;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="vertical" id="v1">V1</div>
    <div class="vertical" id="v2">V2</div>
    <div class="vertical" id="v3">V3</div>
    <div class="vertical" id="v4">V4</div>
    <div class="vertical" id="v5">V5</div>
    <div class="horizontal" id="h1">H</div>
    <div class="horizontal" id="h2">H</div>
    <div class="square">S</div>
    <div class="square">S</div>
    <div class="square">S</div>
    <div class="square">S</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is really a good answer but no support for I.E. I would like a solution without grid css.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Unite Gallary](http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=tiles-columns). It is completely free and very easy to use. Try reading their documentation and it will be easy to use. Below is a screenshot. [image]

[Unite Gallary](http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=tiles-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old technique and is generally frowned upon, but you could just use a `<table>` if you have to support IE, as you specified in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457557/complex-grid-with-images/51486069#51486069).

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Corina</td>
    <td>Lydia</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Reinas</td>
    <td colspan="2">Elise</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Vegerra</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Agapi</td>
    <td>Amira</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Filipa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daisy</td>
    <td colspan="2">Josephine</td>
    <td>Amarylis</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Be advised that the table does not react to `height` as one may expect when using percentages (at least in Firefox 61.0).

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Corina</td>
    <td>Lydia</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Reinas</td>
    <td colspan="2">Elise</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Vegerra</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Agapi</td>
    <td>Amira</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Filipa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daisy</td>
    <td colspan="2">Josephine</td>
    <td>Amarylis</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*BTW: After writing this table I can see why this kind of layout would not be preferred to use because it is very irritating that in some rows there are just columns missing.*